# Upgrading from sierra to catalina while maintaining dual boot with kali

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina

Yesterday I installed Kali linux in macbook air having macos (sierra).today I downloaded Catalina through appstore . It downloads Catalina file  around 7gb and to install it reboots
MAGIC
While rebooting it enters into Linux grub option.
Then I tried to reboot again with option button
It show Macintosh disk and I clicked it.then
Normal sierra opened
What about Catalina os . I have files of Catalina

Answer (score 1):

the mac reboots at the upgrade installation, some installation routines happens after this reboot. With re-booting into grub you canceled the installtion. Deacitvate grub to do a full installtion with maybe needed firmware upgrade...